# VB Console Mode text files

Tags: vb.net, file-io, console

I'm new to VB console mode but I have to use it for my programming paper and one of the programs i have to code for requires me to create a text file called "Carsales.text"

The thing is I'm using my textbook as a guide and this is the example they provide

```
Dim FileHandle As IO.StreamWriter
Dim LineOfText As String
FileHandle = New
IO.StreamWriter("Sample.TXT")

FileHandle.WriteLine(LineOfText)
FileHandle.Close()
```

I tried to run it first to see how exactly it works but

```
FileHandke = New
IO.StreamWriter("Sample.txt")
```

both produce 2 errors:

Error 1 Type expected

Error   2   'StreamWriter' is a type in 'IO' and cannot be used as an expression.

Considering this is exactly what's in the textbook I don't know how to modify it to solve the problem

Comment: You need to put the assignment on 1 line.  Try `FileHandle = New IO.StreamWriter("Sample.TXT")`.

Answer (score 0):

> Error 1 Type expected

This error is because your class is on a new line and need's moved up. The second error happens because of this issue...

> Error 2 'StreamWriter' is a type in 'IO' and cannot be used as an expression.

This error is because `IO.StreamWriter("Sample.TXT")` is on a different line as VS is interpreting it as an expression . You need to move this up to where `FileHandle = New` is. Then it should look like this:

```
  FileHandle = New IO.StreamWriter("Sample.TXT")
```

On another note: ***Wrap your StreamWriter in a Using statement***, very important. When you wrap it in a `Using` statement it helps to release resources used by the `TextWriter` object. If you do not wrap it, at least call `FileHandle.Dispose()` after `FileHandle.Close()`...

For example...

```
Using FileHandle As New IO.StreamWriter("Sample.TXT")
   FileHandle.WriteLine(LineOfText)
   FileHandle.Close()
End Using
```